# Conditional in Loop MASM x86 Assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, masm, irvine32

I am using the Irvine library.

I want to iterate through a DWORD array while checking if each value is in the range of j and k. The code I have does not work currently. Here is what I have:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
COMMENT !
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO, code:DWORD
DumpRegs PROTO
!

.data
myArr DWORD 1h,2h,3h,4h
prompt BYTE "Enter the value for j and k: ", 0
counter BYTE ?

.code
MAIN PROC
  mov eax, 0              ;    sum

  ; Get user vals for j and k
  mov edx, OFFSET prompt
  CALL WriteString
  CALL ReadInt
  mov ebx, eax

  CALL ReadInt
  mov edx, eax



  CALL sumArr             ; Call #1  *****

  mov ebx, 5              ;   j = 5
  mov edx, 8              ;   k = 8

  CALL sumArr             ; Call #2  *****


Main endP



sumArr PROC USES esi ecx edx ebx
    mov counter, LENGTHOF myArr
    mov esi, OFFSET myArr   ;    location pointer
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF myArr ;    size


    getArr:
      cmp ebx, [esi]
      jae aboveEqual
      add esi, TYPE myArr


    aboveEqual:
      cmp edx, [esi]
      jbe inRange

    inRange:
      add eax, [esi]

      LOOP getArr
    CALL DumpRegs
    RET
sumArr ENDP
```

I want to be able to do a comparison for each element in the array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to zero EAX in SUMARR.
Both `cmp ebx,[esi]` and `cmp edx,[esi]` must have source and destination operands switched place.
Move `add esi, TYPE myArr` right before the LOOP instruction.
If the conditional jumps are not taken then unconditionally jump to the `add esi, TYPE myArr` instruction.

In `mov ecx, LENGTHOF myArr` will the immediate be 4 or will it be 16?